# Proving convexity of $X=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 ; ax + by \le c\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$, how can I prove that $X=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 ; ax + by \le c\}$ is convex in $\mathbb R^2$? I know that $X$ is convex when $u,v \in X \rightarrow [u,v] \subset X$, where $[u,v]$ is the line segment whose extremes are $u$ and $v$, i.e., $[u,v]=\{(1-t)u+tv; 0\leq t \leq 1 \}$. But I dont know how to solve the problem under these assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any $(x_1,y_1) \in X$ and $(x_2,y_2) \in X$. Hence, we have
$$ax_1 + by_1 \leq c \text{ and }ax_2 + by_2 \leq c$$
Now can you show that for $t \in [0,1]$,
$$a(tx_1) + b(ty_1) + a((1-t)x_2) + b((1-t)y_2) \leq c ?$$

Comment: Hello. Your expression equals $ax_1 + bx_1 + \frac{(1-t)}{t}[ax_2 + by_2]$. When t tends to zero, the expression goes to $\infty$. So, I can't see the inequality.

Comment: @Walterr There's no $t$ in no denomimator.

Comment: I'm sorry. The conclusion is plain to see, Thanks.